# Coroutine doesnt run on second try?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine, ienumerator

Currently, I have this process on my OnGUI function:

```cs
void OnGUI ()
{
   // process here that adds item on list
    Counter = list.Count();
}
```

I have this code that runs a function when Counter value is changed.

```cs
private IEnumerator coroutine = null;
private int counter = 0;
private int limit = 5;
public int Counter 
{
    get{ return this.counter; }
    set
    {
         this.counter =  value;
         if(this.counter == limit)
         { 
             if(this.coroutine != null){ return; } // already running
             this.coroutine = StartProcess();
             StartCoroutine(this.coroutine); }
    }
}
```

StartProcess contains this :

```cs
StartProcess ()
{
  yield return StartCorotuine (Process1);
  yield return StartCorotuine (Process2);
}
```

Everything works smoothly on my first run but on my second run, it seems like my Counter function is no longer running even if my condition is met?

Comment: Where do you set it back to null? `if(this.coroutine != null){ return; } // already running`

Comment: ahh i see. so i should probably add 'coroutine = null' after my 'yield return StartCoroutine(Process2);'. Is that right?

Comment: You should do what is correct for your code. It seems you don't want to start another while one is running, but only you know why you wrote it that way.

Comment: Yes you need to reset coroutine = null at the end of StartProcess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a coroutine finishes the pointer to it is still valid, it does not reset to null, you get to keep a handler to a dead coroutine, just add =null at the end and you should be fine